# Rsync files from remote using find

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, find, rsync

I would like to synchronize remote files with local directory. Files must be from today 0AM.
I tried to download files with this command, but this method does not work.
How can I achieve my goal?

```
ssh user@192.168.1.100 'find /home/user/test/ -mtime -1 -type f' | rsync --archive --verbose -zz --human-readable --rsh='ssh user@192.168.1.100:/home/user/test/' '/e/rc/'
```

/e/rc/ is my local windows directory - script is launched from git bash console (find and rsync are avaible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commands have 2 problems
1) ssh password is constantly asked so made 2 separated commands to list and copy.
2) Items in list contains /home/user/test which rsync will try to copy to /home/user/test/home/user/test, throwing an error. Files basename is needed.

```
# we need to get file basename since rsync+ssh will copy with respect to user home
files=$(ssh user@192.168.0.10 "find /home/user/test/ -mtime -1 -type f -exec basename {} ';'")
# do the actual copy reading list of files-from stdout
echo "$files" | rsync -avz --files-from=- user@192.168.0.10:test/ '/e/rc/'
```

I don't use `git bash`so if `$(...)`expression does not work try to use backticks or use a full fledged bash.